# Permissions doesn't change while mounting windows directories (mount.cifs)

Tags: centos, samba, cifs

I used this command:
`mount.cifs //192.168.1.106/ukv_sftp$ /home/admin/public_html/remote -o credentials=/root/.smbcredentials, uid=500, gid=500`

but permissions set only for root user, uid=500 and gid=500 doesn't work! I don't understand what's wrong with it. I read [this](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html) manual and tried all the credentials, but nothing work. Help please!

Here's result of `ls -l /home/admin/public_html/`:

> 0 `drwxr-xr-x` 1 root root 0 Nov 12 14:55 remote

Comment: You should strip spaces between options `-o credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,uid=500,gid=500`

Comment: YEAH! It works!!! Thank you man! I was inattentive... ;)